# Error in GMaven Plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, groovy, maven-plugin, gmaven-plugin

Whenever I execute the gmaven plugin, I get the following problem

> `org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal 'org.codehaus.groovy.maven:gmaven-plugin:1.0-rc-5:generateStubs': Mojo execution failed.`

The relevant section of my POM is below. Any thoughts why?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-rc-5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                        <directory>${project.build.testDirectory}</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                    </fileset>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a mismatch with my groovy libraries and gmaven versions. I cleared out my local repository and updated to the latest versions. Now all is back to normal.

Comment: It's enough to remove org/codehaus/groovy and org/codehaus/gmaven directories.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no formatting issue with the POM (either in this section or in another section of your POM)?
See [this bug](http://www.eclipse.org/newsportal/article.php?id=253&group=eclipse.technology.m2e#253) for more details, also [reported here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1192).